Tableau prep extract not updating in tableau desktop
I'm having an issue with my Tableau dashboard not showing updated data. Here's my setup:
 1. I have a Tableau Prep flow that creates a data extract daily.(works fine) 
 2. This extract is the data source for my Tableau dashboard.(works fine) 
 3. My dashboard uses an extract of this data source, not a live connection but an extract in 
    tableau desktop, for smooth performance. (not refreshing the updated data from tableau
    prep)

The problem is:
 - The Tableau Prep flow is running fine and updating the data extract daily.
 - However, my dashboard isn't refreshing its own extract of this data source.
 - When I publish the workbook to Tableau Cloud, I don't see an option to schedule.

Am I missing a step in this process? How can I ensure my dashboard's extract updates along with the data source extract created by the Prep flow?

Why are you making an extract of an extract?

Here is the documentation for scheduling refreshes on Tableau Cloud, I believe the option moved to Explore
